# Converting a Typescript array of objects to an object

Tags: typescript

I have this object type

```
interface MyObject<T> {
  id: string
  value: T
}
```

And this array type

```
type MyArray = MyObject[]
```

Now i need to declare a generic type that defines a new object based on `id`s and `value`s in the `MyObject`'s in the `MyArray`. In my mind in should look something like this, but i am not sure what to put inside the `{{}}`'s.

```
interface MyArrayObject<MyArray> {
    [id: {{MyArray[number].id}} ]: {{typeof MyArray[number].value}}
}
```

### Example

```
const arr = [
  { id: "key1", value: 123 },
  { id: "key2", value: "abc" }
]
```

The resulting object contains all `MyObject.id`s and their respective `MyObject.value`.

```
const arrObject = {
  "key1": 123
  "key2": "abc" 
}
```

Is it even possible to type this?

Comment: You cannot strongly type *each* of the keys based on the array contents. Typescript  types are compile time constructs (i.e. you "run" JavaScript).

Comment: See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRGnvN) example. If it works for you I will provide an answer

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Thank you! This is exactly what i need, although its slightly more complex than anticipated ;)

Comment: Can I mark your question as a duplicate ? As you might have noticed, you can `reduce` your tuple in two ways: fist is a recursive type just like in linked answer and the second one with using `UnionToIntersection` and simple iteration through array keys

Comment: Sure you can and yes, i noticed ;)